# MIME::Lite not working with SMTP

Tags: perl, email, smtp, sendmail

I have been using [`MIME::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite) for a while to send to my mailing list without any problems, but have recently decided to use SMTP authentication as I've heard it's better for email source verification.

I can't get it to work. I checked for and installed the [`Net::SMTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP) module which I understand `Mime::Lite` uses for this.

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
my $mailHost = 'mail.domain.com';
my $user     = 'username';
my $pass     = 'password';
my $html     = 'someHTML';
my $text     = 'someText';

use MIME::Lite;

MIME::Lite->send( 'smtp', $mailHost, AuthUser => $user, AuthPass => $pass );

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => 'Mailing list <list@domain.com>',
    To      => $email,
    Subject => $subject,
    Type    => 'multipart/alternative'
);

$msg->attach(
    Type => 'TEXT',
    Data => $text
);

$msg->attach(
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => $html
);

$msg->send();
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain exactly what unexpected behaviour you are seeing. Also, show us your previous code that worked, so we can compare.

Comment: The mail doesn't send. I'm not even sure how to debug this or where to check for any errors. This is on a shared hosting server. The only difference between the above code and the one that works is the addition of the line:

`MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $mailHost, AuthUser=>$user, AuthPass=>$pass);`
Which, according to CPAN doc invokes Net::SMTP to send the message.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Is anything written to the mail log?

Comment: Where would I find that? I'm using cPanel on a  Linux server.

Comment: Depends on which Linux distribution you're using. In /var/log. Perhaps called maillog.

Comment: Sorry can't find it.  Nothing in var/log. No maillog. Possibly I should look for another package to use anyway.

Comment: Add `Debug` option to Net::SMTP params : `MIME::Lite->send( 'smtp', $mailHost,  Debug=>1, ...);` . It may provide you some useful hints.

Comment: also, try just setting the values in "MIME::Lite->send" in the call to $msg->send();   since it looks like your mailhost, user,pass stay the same anyway, setting the default via MIME::Lite->send probably doesn't add that much value.   Then look at answer and prepare to switch to a better supported module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Authenticating through SMTP requires `NET::SMTP`. The following code now works for sending email with `MIME::LITE` and `SMTP`:

```
my $mailHost = 'domain.com';
my $user     = 'username';
my $pass     = 'password';
my $html     = 'someHTML';
my $text     = 'someText';

use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;

MIME::Lite->send( 'smtp', $mailHost, AuthUser => $user, AuthPass => $pass );

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => 'Mailing list <list@domain.com>',
    To      => $email,
    Subject => $subject,
    Type    => 'multipart/alternative'
);

$msg->attach(
    Type => 'TEXT',
    Data => $text
);

$msg->attach(
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => $html
);

$msg->send();
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend MIME::Lite. And I'm not alone in that. The current [documentation for the module](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT!) says:

> **WAIT!**
>
> MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a
>   number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and
>   Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite
>   continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large
>   amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives.
>   Please consider using something else.

I'd recommend [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) or [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer). They both have support for SMTP authentication.

But, of course, this might not solve your problem at all. If the problem is with your SMTP configuration then this change will get you no closer. I recommend asking the sysadmin where the mail logs are kept so you can see what the actual problems are.